# Cannot remove HDD Password

Tags: hard-drive, bios, passwords, dell-inspiron

I have set a HDD Password to my Dell Inspiron 3000 Series Laptop. I can reset my password but cannot remove it. I can't find a option to remove the password in the BIOS screen.

[image]

How will I be able to remove this password? Please advice.

Comment: Can you set it to nothing?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Didn't check that.. Let me try and let you know

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yes.. That worked. Please put it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off the password requirement by entering nothing in the password field when changing it. This sets it as nothing and sets the flag to `Not Set`.